# OpenStreetMap data quality

Tags: data

my company is considering switching from using Bing Maps to an open data source mapping option like MapBox. We are also looking into options like Google Maps.

My only question is what the quality of data is like for OpenStreetMaps. Its hard to jump around maps and check for this. I have done a little of this and have seen places where it appears OpenStreetMaps has better data and vice versa, however this is a very small sample.

Does anyone have a good general view of how the data quality compares between OpenStreetMaps and options like Google or Nokia?

Thanks

Comment: The related duplicate question is three years old now. Openstreetmap has improved a lot since then in many parts of the world, the other sources not. Except for places where Google copied data from Openstreetmap...

Comment: I'd recommend reading the following paper: Neis, P. and Zielstra D. (2014): Recent Developments and Future Trends in Volunteered Geographic Information Research: The Case of OpenStreetMap. Future Internet, 6(1):76-106. Especially the reference which contains more than 150 papers dealing with OSM, VGI and data quality.